# Laravel assign middleware to auth route

Tags: laravel, middleware

I want to assign middelware to the register post route.
For example like:

```
Route::post('contact', [
    'as'    => 'contact-store',
    'uses'  => 'ContactmeController@contactUSPost'
])->middleware(\Spatie\Honeypot\ProtectAgainstSpam::class);
```

My routes files contains

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

which generates your login and register routes automagically.

How do I assign the middleware ProtectAgainstSpam to the register POST method with Auth::routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use it by using group route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
    Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
});
```

`Auth::routes()` is just a helper class that helps you generate all the routes required for user authentication. You can browse the code here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php instead.

Here are the routes

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
        // Authentication Routes...
        $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
        $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
    
        // Registration Routes...
        $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
        $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
    
        // Password Reset Routes...
        $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
        $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
        $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
        $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');

  });
```